# Twilio Conversations Group MMS not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, mms, twilio-conversations

I have a Twilio Trial account with a number that has SMS/MMS enabled.

I want to use the number in a group MMS chat.
I have a very basic test that I created after following the tutorial on [Tut](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/group-texting)

The two numbers I'm attempting to send to have been verified. I'm able to send messages to these numbers individually, just not in a group chat. Please see code below

```
const accountSid = "ACCOUNT_SID";
const authToken = "AUTHO_TOKEN";
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

(async () => {
    const conversation = await client.conversations.v1.conversations.create({ friendlyName: 'TEST' });
    const participant = await client.conversations.v1.conversations(conversation.sid)
        .participants
        .create({
            identity: 'realEstateAgent',
            'messagingBinding.projectedAddress': '+TWILIO_NUMBER'
        });

const one = await client.conversations.v1.conversations(conversation.sid)
    .participants
    .create({ 'messagingBinding.address': '+NUM_1' });

const two = await client.conversations.v1.conversations(conversation.sid)
    .participants
    .create({ 'messagingBinding.address': '+NUM_2' });


const msg = await client.conversations.v1.conversations(conversation.sid)
    .messages
    .create({
        body: 'This is a test message',
        author: 'realEstateAgent'
    })
    .then(message => console.log(message.sid));

})();
```

Everything appears to run successfully and the `message.sid` gets logged out. However, none of the numbers receive the message. But, this same code works if I just send to one number.

Messaging logs show that message has been `sent` to both numbers, but not delivered. It doesn't say anything else making me believe an error occurred.

Any Insights?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen any additional press release, so this is likely your [issue](https://www.twilio.com/en-us/changelog/limitation-to-group-mms). Twilio had issues at the carrier level and blocked groupmms for all new customers.  So if you have an older account(or access to one) you can potentially use it, bit otherwise as of their last statement you cant use it at the moment still.

The work around ive seen is to use [conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/fundamentals) and distributed it a message via a one to many channel, but i have not tried this myself and im not familiar with the drawback.

Also their are limitations on the phone numbers as well

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the link. It does seem like that is what's going on. Disappointing that Twilio has been so cryptic about this.

So, in my code above, I'm actually using Convos. I followed https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/group-texting

Any insights nows?